# Forwarding query string with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule but I've some serious problems with forwarding query string.
I also tried `[QSA]` flag but it didn't work.

Following the correct request:

```
/localhost/registry/registry.php?id=something&password=somethingelse&uri=whatever
```

And I would change into something like this:

```
/localhost/registry/register
```

with the same post query (id=something&password=somethingelse&uri=whatever).
At this point, my .htaccess would modify the above request in the following one:

```
/localhost/registry/registry.php?request=register&id=something&password=somethingelse&uri=whatever
```

Then, I tried the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^register$ http://localhost/registry/registry.php?request=$0&$1 [QSA]
```

But, after the last '&', nothing is showed and the $1 variable is empty.
What kind of rewrite rule I have to write?

Thanks in advance.

**!!! SOLUTION !!!**

```
RewriteRule ^register$ /registry/registry.php?request=$0 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^register$ /registry/registry.php?request=$0  [QSA]
```

if you go to `http://localhost/registry/register?id=1`, then query string would be(from php) :

```
array(2) {
  ["request"]=>
  string(8) "register"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
The http status returned is 400.
If I add a rewrite rule like this:

>RewriteRule ^register$ http://localhost/registry/registry.php [QSA]

the request (initial a POST request) is redirect with a 302 http status but the following request (http://localhost/registry/registry.php) is a GET, not a POST.
Why? Further more, the QSA didn't work again...

Comment: is there any `.htaccess` file in parent folders?

Comment: Not in the parent folder, but in localhost/registry. Why? The .htaccess works well. Is the rewrite rule that doesn't work. Now I fixed with PHP forwarding all requests to the registry.php file but I don't like this solution...

Comment: `localhost` in your `RewriteRule` is directory or it's host name?

Comment: Sorry Death I tried but I got the same problem.
With GET requests it works but not with POST: htaccess redirect the original request (POST http://localhost/registry/register?id=5) to a new GET request without the fields (it seems that QSA flag doesn't work): GET http://localhost/registry/registry.php?request=register. That's all.
Any other suggestions?
I can't really believe that does not exist a solution for this kind of problem.
Anyway, thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Ok, I modified the rewrite rule in: 
RewriteRule ^register$ /registry/registry.php?request=$0 [QSA] and it worked good (without http://localhost)! Thanks a lot Death ;)